# FIind the combined values in sql

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
    ID INT,
    PLACE VARCHAR(255),
    FOOD VARCHAR(100)
    );

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES
                     (1,'VZG',NULL),
                     (1,NULL,'IDLI'),
                     (2,'HYD',NULL),
                     (2,NULL,'BIR'),
                     (3,'AKP',NULL),
                     (4,NULL,'MILK');

SELECT * FROM T1;
```

======================================

#I Need output TABLE to be

```
  1 VZG IDLI 
  2 HYD BIR
  3 AKP NULL
  4 NULL MILK
```

============================

I am unable to get the query.

Comment: Giving an example output of the query can be quite ambiguous. Please provide more details to the question, for example you could say that for each value of id you want the first non-null value of place and food to be displayed if any.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the max from the values. .

```
select t.id, max(t.place), max(t.food)
from T1 t
group by t.id
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YSms1omD).

Comment: Hi,@slaakso I wonder if it's really necessary to use a self join. The query gets the same result without it.

Comment: @blabla_bingo It is actually not. Shortened the answer and gave you a vote